# Error when starting Stardog server

Tags: java, windows, exception, stardog

It worked well a few weeks ago, but now I am having problems just when starting the server with `stardog-admin.bat server start`.
When I do it, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/C:/Users/quico/Desktop/Stardog/stardog-5.3.3/client/api/guice-4.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
at com.complexible.common.rdf.model.AbstractStardogLongLiteral.(AbstractStardogLongLiteral.java:25)
at com.complexible.common.rdf.model.StardogLongIntegerLiteral.(StardogLongIntegerLiteral.java:17)
at com.complexible.common.rdf.model.StardogValueFactory.createLiteral(StardogValueFactory.java:436)
at com.complexible.stardog.index.dictionary.ValueInliner$IntegerInliner.extract(ValueInliner.java:431)
at com.complexible.stardog.index.dictionary.ValueInliner.extract(ValueInliner.java:108)
at com.complexible.stardog.index.dictionary.InliningMappingDictionary.getValue(InliningMappingDictionary.java:91)
at com.complexible.stardog.index.dictionary.DelegatingMappingDictionary.getValue(DelegatingMappingDictionary.java:67)
at com.complexible.stardog.security.index.SecurityIndexes.getSecurityIndexVersion(SecurityIndexes.java:176)
at com.complexible.stardog.security.index.SecurityIndexes.initialize(SecurityIndexes.java:83)
at com.complexible.stardog.security.index.IndexSystemSecurityManagerFactory.create(IndexSystemSecurityManagerFactory.java:58)
at com.complexible.stardog.BaseStardogModule.getSystemSecurityManager(BaseStardogModule.java:200)
at com.complexible.stardog.BaseStardogModule$$FastClassByGuice$$920e5968.invoke()
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:272)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:172)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.get(Multibinder.java:375)
at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.get(Multibinder.java:258)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:104)
at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:104)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:167)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.initKernel(Stardog.java:213)
at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.(Stardog.java:206)
at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.(Stardog.java:60)
at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog$StardogBuilder.create(Stardog.java:597)
at com.complexible.stardog.cli.impl.ServerStart.call(ServerStart.java:162)
at com.complexible.stardog.cli.impl.ServerStart.call(ServerStart.java:41)
at com.complexible.stardog.cli.CLIBase.execute(CLIBase.java:55)
at com.complexible.stardog.cli.admin.CLI.main(CLI.java:186)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
… 76 more
```

I have searched on the Internet, but can't find a solution. I also have tried to download the new version of Stardog (5.3.3), because I got the 5.3.1, and redo the [quick start guide](https://www.stardog.com/docs/#_windows).

I have to mention I am installing it on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the Java version, I had installed Java 10, and it supports Java 8.